# Multiple Chart objects on one sheet

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I'm trying to place two chart objects on a single sheet and encountering difficulties with Excel 2010.

My code was working fine with a single chart object but when I added an additional chart: the chart type, title and other attributes are not registering  up on the second chart.

The two charts should have the same structure but reference a different column on the sheet. I've looked around but couldn’t find a solution. Please suggest how to fix this problem. I’m posting partial code only but can post the rest of the code if it's helpful. Sorry if the code is too long...

I really appreciate your help.

```
Function GraphMFI(Arr() As Variant, Arr2() As Variant, ChartName As String, ChartName2 As String)

Dim i As Long, l As Long
Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range
Dim MyArY() As Variant, MyArX() As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long, iVal As Long
Dim Count As Long, SumArr As Long, AvgC As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False

'***********************************************************************
'Code that calculates x and y values not shown
'**************************************************************************
On Error Resume Next

'~~~~~~~~~chart code begins

Call DeleteallCharts 'delete all existing charts from active sheet
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~add both charts~~~~~~
Set objChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
(Left:=410, Width:=500, Top:=15, Height:=250)
objChart.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

Set objChart2 = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
(Left:=410, Width:=500, Top:=300, Height:=250)
objChart.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~add both charts~~~~~~

Dim objChartSeriesColl As SeriesCollection
Dim objChartSeriesColl2 As SeriesCollection

Set objChartSeriesColl = objChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
Set objChartSeriesColl2 = objChart2.Chart.SeriesCollection
'delete all chart series

'~~~~~~~~~~~first chart
With objChartSeriesColl.NewSeries '~~~raw data

.Name = "Inner Run Variability"
.Values = Arr
.XValues = rng
.MarkerSize = 10
.
    'code not shown
End With

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~First Chart
With objChartSeriesColl.NewSeries '~~~average series one
Dim nPts As Long
.Name = "Mean"
.Values = AvgArr '~~~~average of Negative control
.XValues = rng '~~~dates
'.AxisGroup = xlSecondary
.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers

 'With mySrs
        nPts = .Points.Count
        .Points(nPts).ApplyDataLabels _
            Type:=xlDataLabelsShowValue, _
            AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False
        .Points(nPts).DataLabel.Text = .Name
        .Points(nPts).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlDataLabelsShowValue, _
                    AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False
With .DataLabels
            .AutoScaleFont = False
            .Font.Size = 10
            .Font.ColorIndex = 3
            .Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Orientation = xlHorizontal
        End With
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

End With

With objChartSeriesColl.NewSeries '~~plus two stdev series two
.Name = "plus 2 stdev"
.Values = TwoPlusSdtDevArr
.XValues = rng '~~~dates
End With

With objChartSeriesColl.NewSeries 'minus three stdev series three
.Name = "minus 2 stdev"
.Values = TwiceStdDevArr
.XValues = rng
.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
End With

'~~~~~~~~~~~Second chart
With objChartSeriesColl2.NewSeries '~~~raw data
.Name = "Inner Run Variability"
.Values = Arr2
.XValues = rng
.MarkerSize = 10
End With

'~~~~~adding series to the second chart

With objChartSeriesColl2.NewSeries '~~~average
Dim nPts2 As Long
.Name = "Mean"
.Values = AvgArr
.XValues = rng '~~~dates
.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers

End With

'....more series not shown here

With objChart

            .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" 'changes Xaxis text format
            .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "General" 'changes Yaxis Text Format
            .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart) 'adds chart title above chart
            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis) 'adds Xaxis title
            .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated) 'adds rotated Yaxis Title

            .ChartTitle.Text = ChartName  'adds chart title above chart
            .SetElement (msoElementLegendNone)

            '~~~~~~~~~~~~set plot area
            With .PlotArea
                    .Width = .Width / 2
                    .Height = .Height / 2
                    .Left = 16
                    .Top = 16
                    .Width = 450
                End With
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            With .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
                .AxisTitle.Text = "Run Dates" 'renames Xaxis title to "X Title"
                .AxisTitle.Font.Bold = True
          End With
            With .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
                .AxisTitle.Text = "Sample Dates" 'renames Xaxis title to "X Title"
                .AxisTitle.Text = "MFI Values" 'renames Yaxis title to "Y Title"
            End With
            .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = ChartMin '~~adds min

            .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = ChartMax '~~ adds max
            .Parent.Placement = xlFreeFloating

            With .ChartArea.Format.Line
                .Visible = msoCTrue
                .Style = msoLineSingle
                .Weight = 1
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

            End With

        End With
        '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        'more code
End With

''''~~~~~~~~~~~~~Second Chart begins here

With objChart2
'..........
'code almost the same as 'with objChart'

  Application.EnableEvents = True
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Are you using Excel 2013? I have found that the chart object model is a bit flaky in 2013 and 2016. Try it in Excel 2010 if you have it available.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010 sorry for not clarifying it earlier.